# HTTP Request: Is there a way to do a GET within a GET in linux

Tags: linux, http, get, wget

I am attempting to do a http request within another http request. Is there a way to do this via command line in linux?

```
wget http://request another wget http://request
```

Comment: What do you mean "within"? A request is a request, there's nothing within it. Please explain more clearly

Comment: So basically my first HTTP request requires the second HTTP request (which returns JSON info) as a parameter, so i was wondering if i can call both in one line ?

Comment: You can use `$(command)` to substitute the output of a command into the command line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `$()` to substute the output of a command:

```
wget http://someURL?param="$(wget -O - http://otherURL)"
```

The `-O -` option tells `wget` to write the output to standard output instead of a file.

Comment: `wget` won't print the response to stdout -- `s/wget/curl/g`?

Comment: @GrishaLevit Thanks, I mostly use `curl` myself. I added the `-O` option to send the result to stdout.